# Why is my script suddenly skipping/omiting columns?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a Google Apps Script that worked until a couple of weeks ago.  It iterates through the columns of a specific row, but suddenly it's skipping over columns. There are headers in the second row and my log statements print out the A1 notation properly, but the contents are incorrect.

For example, the data in the spreadsheet has the following value:
A2 Name
B2 Address
C2 City
D2 State
E2 Zip
F2 Email

The output of the trace statements says the following:
A2 Name
B2 City
C2 State
D2 Zip
E2 Email
F2 [empty]

I'm super confused as to why this worked and now doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Here's the code snippet:

```
Logger.log("     column 1, row 2="+sheet.getRange(2,1).getValues()[0][0]+" "+sheet.getRange(2,1).getA1Notation());
Logger.log("     column 2, row 2="+sheet.getRange(2,2).getValues()[0][0]+" "+sheet.getRange(2,2).getA1Notation());
Logger.log("     column 3, row 2="+sheet.getRange(2,3).getValues()[0][0]+" "+sheet.getRange(2,3).getA1Notation());
Logger.log("     column 4, row 2="+sheet.getRange(2,4).getValues()[0][0]+" "+sheet.getRange(2,4).getA1Notation());
Logger.log("     column 5, row 2="+sheet.getRange(2,5).getValues()[0][0]+" "+sheet.getRange(2,5).getA1Notation());
Logger.log("     column 6, row 2="+sheet.getRange(2,6).getValues()[0][0]+" "+sheet.getRange(2,6).getA1Notation());
Logger.log("     column 7, row 2="+sheet.getRange(2,7).getValues()[0][0]+" "+sheet.getRange(2,7).getA1Notation());
```

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example of your code you're using, for us to better look what you're trying to achieve practically.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help need to provide [mcve]. Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function elfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,1,7).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i)=> {
    r.forEach((c,j) => {
      Logger.log(`column ${j+1} row 2 = ${r[j]}  ${sh.getRange(2,j+1).getA1Notation()}`);
    })
  })
}

Execution log
5:05:34 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:05:34 PM  Info    column 1 row 2 = 13  A2
5:05:34 PM  Info    column 2 row 2 = 8  B2
5:05:34 PM  Info    column 3 row 2 = 14  C2
5:05:34 PM  Info    column 4 row 2 = 14  D2
5:05:34 PM  Info    column 5 row 2 = 2  E2
5:05:34 PM  Info    column 6 row 2 = 17  F2
5:05:34 PM  Info    column 7 row 2 = 1  G2
5:05:35 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 |
| 13 | 8 | 14 | 14 | 2 | 17 | 1 |

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the code snippet you provided still skips a couple of columns.  This is so strange.  I tried changing the value of the column and trying a different row, but neither helped.

Comment: It works for me just fine maybe is not the code maybe it has something to do with the spreadsheet content

Comment: Problem solved. I had a hidden sheet that had the exact same name as the sheet that I thought was causing problems.  Ugh!